# 404 page not found - Yet open admin page it works

Tags: permalinks, wp-admin, 404-error

Having a weird problem on a new site we are putting together. Everything is working OK with one exception - one page always returns a 404 page not found.

In the admin pages, if the page is veiwed or previewed it works fine - in fact, if I open the site in another browesr tab - the site works fine. As soon as I log out of close the admin page, the very same page when refreshed comes up as 404 page not found.

I've tried the ususal disabling plug ins, even tried refreshing permalinks - which was a disaster as the category posts on the front page started showing all the text instead of just the featured image. Its back to "normal" now - but even creating a new post with the same name doesn't work

I really don't understand whats going on here - seems to have a mind of its own!

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated - although seemingly a simple problem is is proving to be a show stopper!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would be interested in what the page slug is...perhaps some non-ASCII characters in there?

And, what happens if you change the page slug?

Maybe there is another component in the page request that is causing the 404. Look at all request for that page (via Developer Tools in your browser) to see which request is the 404.

Comment: Hi - Thanks for the reply and suggestions. The slug is "luxury-flowers" without the quotes. as per your suggestion, I renamed this to "luxury-flowers1" and this works fine... I can only assume there is some sort of conflict?

Couldn't see anything obvious in developer tools... but I'll keep digging - presumably if the same page loads OK with a new slug its more to do with the naming??

Thanks again

Comment: It's possible that the page's slug name got corroded in some way somewhere in the database. So a rename of it fixed the corrosion. You could try renaming it back to the original and see if that works, which would indicate that the entry in the db was the problem, rather than another page with the same name.
If this worked for you, mark the answer as correct to help others that might get to your question because of a similar problem.